# Is it idiomatic to take advantage of python's pass-by-sharing of mutable data structures like lists?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, idioms

I know that in Python, because it's pass-by-sharing, if I pass a mutable object (like a list) to a function, and then use that function to mutate it, I don't need to explicitly pass it back, because the caller can see the changes:

```
def add_to_list(list_of_nums):
    list_of_nums.append(26)

my_list = [12]
add_to_list(my_list)
print my_list  # >>>[12, 26]
```

So this works. But is it a good idea/good python practice? My gut says it's not (the same way global variables are almost always a bad idea), but maybe that's just because I first learned C++ in all its pass-by-value glory.

And yes, I know that I can code my way around this (say by creating a class), but the question is, should I, or is this generally seen as acceptable practice?

Comment: `pass-by-reference` is the term

Comment: @danidee: "Pass by reference" is a little different... Python is actually pass by value, but the value may be a pointer to an object which is shared.

Comment: i'll also suggest you go through this http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: @DietrichEpp i'll rather say `pass-by-object-reference` since objects are just passed around with names bound to them

Comment: FWIW, I got the 'pass-by-sharing' nomenclature from here: http://eev.ee/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-passing/ and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing. Of the different alternatives, it seemed the most descriptive.

Comment: @danidee: "Pass-by-object-reference" is just a new name for "pass by value" when all your values are references to objects.  That's why we say Python is pass by value, just like Java and C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think whether or not this is "acceptable" will be determined by the context and how well the function is named. keep [Pep 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) in mind: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Python fully supports functional programming, and in that case, modifying objects that are passed in is often expected. If the function is named appropriately and documented well, I think it's fine. Your example illustrates this pretty well. The function is called `add_to_list`, which pretty explicitly says what the function does.

If your program/script takes more of an object-oriented approach, modifying passed-in objects should be replaced by creating the appropriate classes instead, like the native `list` class in your example - it has an `append()` method that modifies the list instead of passing the list into a separate function.

The key is to be consistent with your paradigm and well documented. If you cover both of those bases, I think it's acceptable.